# How can I edit date ranges in PHP?

Tags: php, sql, excel

I wrote a system that combines or separates the occupancy dates from the hotels according to the quota data and creates an excel. Everything works properly, I just have a small problem in the date section.

Let me explain the problem exactly as follows:

When separating the date of the data entered in the status data, it does not separate some dates, usually the dates it does not separate are the start dates. I couldn't figure out why.

I am sharing my code blocks with you below. I am also sharing my database data. I will also share my original output and the output I want to get.

Excel generating section. I only shared the part that does the parsing.

```
/////////////////////// EXCEL ISLEMLERI
    $hcode = $veri[0]->hcode;
    $rtype = $veri[0]->rtype;
    $mailsubject = $veri[0]->mailsubject;
    $veriExcel = HALIL::sorgula("SELECT * FROM vakanzfillrooms WHERE hcode = ?", array($hcode));
    $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
    $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
    $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'BCH');
    $sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'Allotment Request Form');
    $sheet->setCellValue('F1', "Sold" . PHP_EOL . "Rooms");
    $sheet->getStyle('F1')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
    $sheet->setCellValue('G1', "Total" . PHP_EOL . "Allotment");
    $sheet->getStyle('G1')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
    $sheet->setCellValue('H1', "Please fill" . PHP_EOL . "up" . PHP_EOL . "Extra Allot.");
    $sheet->getStyle('H1')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
    $columnHeaders2 = ['Hcode', 'Hotel Name', 'Room Type', 'Start Date', 'End Date'];
    $col2 = 'A';
    foreach ($columnHeaders2 as $header2) {
        $sheet->setCellValue($col2 . '2', $header2);
        $col2++;
    }
    usort($veriExcel, function($a, $b) {
        $odaTipSonuc = strcmp($a->rtype, $b->rtype);
        
        if ($odaTipSonuc == 0) {
            $tarihA = strtotime(str_replace('.', '-', $a->mailsubject));
            $tarihB = strtotime(str_replace('.', '-', $b->mailsubject));
            
            if ($tarihA == $tarihB) {
                return 0;
            }
            return ($tarihA < $tarihB) ? -1 : 1;
        }
        
        return $odaTipSonuc;
    });

    $birlestirilmisVeri = [];
    $birlestirilmisVeri[] = $veriExcel[0]; // İlk satırı başlangıç olarak ekleyin

    for ($i = 1; $i < count($veriExcel); $i++) {
        // Eğer veri "vakanzhcode" tablosunda bulunuyorsa birleştirme
        $queryDurumExcel = "SELECT * FROM vakanzhcode WHERE hcode = ? AND rtype = ? AND mailsubject = ?";
        $paramsDurumExcel = array($veriExcel[$i]->hcode, $veriExcel[$i]->rtype, $veriExcel[$i]->mailsubject);
        $resultDurumExcel = HALIL::sorgula($queryDurumExcel, $paramsDurumExcel);

        if (!empty($resultDurumExcel)) 
        {
            // "vakanzhcode" tablosunda veri bulunuyorsa
            $durumBirlestirmeExcelSorgusu = 'SELECT durum FROM vakanzhcode WHERE hcode = ? AND rtype = ? AND mailsubject = ?';
            $durumExcel = HALIL::sorgula($durumBirlestirmeExcelSorgusu, array($veriExcel[$i]->hcode, $veriExcel[$i]->rtype, $veriExcel[$i]->mailsubject));
            
            if ($durumExcel != 4)
            {
                $birlestirilmisVeri[] = $veriExcel[$i];
                continue;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // "vakanzhcode" tablosunda veri bulunmuyorsa diğer koşulları kontrol et
            $onceki = strtotime(str_replace('.', '-', $veriExcel[$i - 1]->mailsubject));
            $suanki = strtotime(str_replace('.', '-', $veriExcel[$i]->mailsubject));
            $birGun = 24 * 60 * 60; // 1 günün saniye cinsinden değeri

            if ($suanki - $onceki === $birGun && $veriExcel[$i - 1]->hcode === $veriExcel[$i]->hcode) {
                if ($veriExcel[$i - 1]->total_kontenjan === $veriExcel[$i]->total_kontenjan &&
                    $veriExcel[$i - 1]->dolu_kontenjan === $veriExcel[$i]->dolu_kontenjan) {
                    $birlestirilmisVeri[count($birlestirilmisVeri) - 1]->mailsubject .= ' - ' . $veriExcel[$i]->mailsubject;
                } else {
                    $birlestirilmisVeri[] = $veriExcel[$i];
                }
            } else {
                $birlestirilmisVeri[] = $veriExcel[$i];
            }
        }
    }

    $row = 3;
    $rowHeader = 1;
    foreach ($birlestirilmisVeri as $veriex) {
        $otelKodu = $veriex->hcode;
        $otelAdi = $veriex->hname;
        $odaTipi = $veriex->rtype;
        $dolulukTarihAraliklari = $veriex->mailsubject;
        $totalKontenjan = $veriex->total_kontenjan;
        $doluKontenjan = $veriex->dolu_kontenjan;
        $tarihAraligi = explode(' - ', $veriex->mailsubject);
        $baslangicTarihi = $tarihAraligi[0];
        $bitisTarihi = end($tarihAraligi);
        $sheet->setCellValue('A' . $row, $otelKodu);
        $sheet->setCellValue('B' . $row, $otelAdi);
        $sheet->setCellValue('C' . $row, $odaTipi);
        $sheet->setCellValue('D' . $row, $baslangicTarihi); // Başlangıç tarihini D sütununa yazın
        $sheet->setCellValue('E' . $row, $bitisTarihi); // Bitiş tarihini E sütununa yazın
        $sheet->setCellValue('F' . $row, $totalKontenjan);
        $sheet->setCellValue('G' . $row, $doluKontenjan);
```

Examples of data in a SQL Database (vakanzhcode):

```
INSERT INTO `vakanzhcode` (`id`, `hcode`, `durum`, `rtype`, `mailsubject`) VALUES
(905, 'ANDEI', '3', 'ESS EINZELZIMME', '05.11.2023'),
(904, 'ANDEI', '3', 'ESS EINZELZIMME', '04.11.2023'),
(903, 'ANDEI', '3', 'ESS EINZELZIMME', '16.03.2024'),
(902, 'ANDEI', '3', 'ESS EINZELZIMME', '15.03.2024'),
(901, 'ANDEI', '3', 'ESS EINZELZIMME', '10.03.2024');
```

Examples of data in a SQL Database (vakanzfillrooms):

```
INSERT INTO `vakanzfillrooms` (`id`, `hcode`, `hname`, `rtype`, `mailsubject`, `mail`, `total_kontenjan`, `dolu_kontenjan`) VALUES
(429, 'ANDEI', 'Delphin Imperial', 'ESS EINZELZIMME', '04.11.2023', 'alper.aslan@bentour.ch', 4, 4),
(430, 'ANDEI', 'Delphin Imperial', 'ESS EINZELZIMME', '05.11.2023', 'alper.aslan@bentour.ch', 4, 4),
(434, 'ANDEI', 'Delphin Imperial', 'ESS EINZELZIMME', '10.03.2024', 'alper.aslan@bentour.ch', 2, 2),
(439, 'ANDEI', 'Delphin Imperial', 'ESS EINZELZIMME', '15.03.2024', 'alper.aslan@bentour.ch', 2, 2),
(440, 'ANDEI', 'Delphin Imperial', 'ESS EINZELZIMME', '16.03.2024', 'alper.aslan@bentour.ch', 2, 2);
```

Original Output:

[image]

The Output I Want:

[image]

Obviously I have tried many different codes, but none of them gave me any results, probably I am looking for the problem elsewhere. I think I need a 3rd eye.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **DateTime** Objects for Date Comparison -->

```
if ($odaTipSonuc == 0) {
    $tarihA = new DateTime(str_replace('.', '-', $a->mailsubject));
    $tarihB = new DateTime(str_replace('.', '-', $b->mailsubject));

    if ($tarihA == $tarihB) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($tarihA < $tarihB) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Your data Entry to **vakanzfillrooms**
has only five records

```
         INSERT INTO `vakanzfillrooms` (`id`, `hcode`, `hname`, `rtype`, `mailsubject`, `mail`, `total_kontenjan`, `dolu_kontenjan`) VALUES
(429, 'ANDEI', 'Delphin Imperial', 'ESS EINZELZIMME', '04.11.2023', 'alper.aslan@bentour.ch', 4, 4),
(430, 'ANDEI', 'Delphin Imperial', 'ESS EINZELZIMME', '05.11.2023', 'alper.aslan@bentour.ch', 4, 4),
(434, 'ANDEI', 'Delphin Imperial', 'ESS EINZELZIMME', '10.03.2024', 'alper.aslan@bentour.ch', 2, 2),
(439, 'ANDEI', 'Delphin Imperial', 'ESS EINZELZIMME', '15.03.2024', 'alper.aslan@bentour.ch', 2, 2),
(440, 'ANDEI', 'Delphin Imperial', 'ESS EINZELZIMME', '16.03.2024', 'alper.aslan@bentour.ch', 2, 2);
```

so the output will have only maximum of 5 records since it loops through records coming from **vakanzfillrooms**, even if you make

```
SELECT * FROM vakanzfillrooms
```

Comment: The result is the same

Comment: the code can produce only 5 records max irrelevant of rest of the data because $veriExcel = HALIL::sorgula("SELECT * FROM vakanzfillrooms WHERE hcode = ?", array($hcode)); will give only 5  records. and for ($i = 1; $i < count($veriExcel); $i++) loop only 5 times max.

Comment: " $queryVeriExcel = "SELECT * FROM vakanzfillrooms WHERE hcode = ?";
 $paramsVeriExcel = array($hcode);
 $veriExcel = HALIL::sorgula($queryVeriExcel, $paramsVeriExcel);
"
I changed the coding like this and it didn't make any difference

Comment: you have only  5 records in your table, its the number of records in your vakanzfillrooms.  so max number of records your get in your output is 5 , even your sql query uses SELECT * FROM vakanzfillrooms . your data entry has only 5 records INSERT INTO `vakanzhcode` (`id`, `hcode`, `durum`, `rtype`, `mailsubject`) VALUES
(905, 'ANDEI', '3', 'ESS EINZELZIMME', '05.11.2023'),
(904, 'ANDEI', '3', 'ESS EINZELZIMME', '04.11.2023'),
(903, 'ANDEI', '3', 'ESS EINZELZIMME', '16.03.2024'),
(902, 'ANDEI', '3', 'ESS EINZELZIMME', '15.03.2024'),
(901, 'ANDEI', '3', 'ESS EINZELZIMME', '10.03.2024');

Comment: No, there are not 5 records in my table, I just gave the information of that many records to explain the problem. Normally, my record count 

Showing rows 0 - 24 (2092 total, Query took 0.0088 seconds.) [mailsubject: [BLOB - 10 B]... - [BLOB - 10 B]...]

Comment: your original output shows what you have given on  Examples of data in a SQL Database (vakanzfillrooms): . in the same order. as per your question there is only 5 records in your table. however you can make sure by running this query one database its self   SELECT id, hcode, hname, rtype, mailsubject, mail, total_kontenjan, dolu_kontenjan FROM vakanzfillrooms WHERE hcode = 'ANDEI' ORDER BY mailsubject ASC